# Angular 2 Service has 2 instances despite not in two providers arrays

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I know the dangers of having a service in more than one providers: [] arrays in components, and that it is best to have services in the app module providers array.

In our case there is one service that is only in the app module providers array, but there is still multiple instances.

Can this be caused by @Injectable in services using that service? That's the only thing I can think of that could cause this.

Comment: How have you established that there are multiple instances?

Comment: I set breakpoints in two places (different files) and in the one place where my subscribe() callback is correctly called the EventEmitter reference in the service has one observer, but in the other place there are no observers.